# import huge batch data file into apache cassandra automatically

Tags: cassandra, insert

I have 1198 CSV file, each more than one gigabyte. I want to import all of them into Apache Cassandra table. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: are all of the CSV are same in term of schema and data type .?

Comment: Do you want all the csv imported into a single table ?

Comment: both of the questions are yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import all your csv into a single table, then move all your csv to a directory. i.e `data` Now you can import the full directory into a table let's say `data_table`

```
COPY data_table FROM 'data/*';
```

By the way, you are importing huge amount of data, you should

- Generating SSTable using CQLSSTableWriter
- Loading existing SSTables using sstableloader